# SQL Server work on small sets of data in a large table

Tags: sql-server, performance

We currently have a large table with millions of records. We keep adding records every day.

We frequently access only the current month data like credit card transactions.

Is there any SQL Server tuning parameter for such type of tables.
I need read optimization than write.

```
select * 
from credit_transaction 
where month = @current_month 
  and customerid = @customerId
```

Comment: Yes, firstly you must create one index for using 2 fields together (`month` and `customerid`).  If the table contains billions of data in the future, you can use table partition technology, this is the best method for very large tables. This technology allows us to physically store data in separate tables or in separate hard disks using conditions. For example - partition by year. But we are will be viewing only one table on the DB. for getting detailed information about this please visit this site:  https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-automate-table-partitioning-in-sql-server/

Comment: An indexed view maybe.